# Background image around a foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach

**I have this php code:**

```
echo '<div class="inventorySimple"> 
        <div class="list">'; 
foreach ($r['result']['achievements']['0']['achievements'] as $item) { 
    echo '<li class="liste" data-tag=', $item['description'], '> 
            <div class="achiev-title">   ', $item['title'], '</div> 
            <div class="description">      ', $item['description'], '</div> 
            <div class="bg-image">';  
    if(!empty($item['criteria'])){ 
        foreach ($item['criteria'] as $item2){             
            echo '<li>', $item2['description'], ' </li>'; 
        } 
    }  
} 

echo '</div></ul></ul>'; 

?>
```

I need a background image behind the results of the second `foreach` loop. I've tried to set:

```
<div class="bg-image">';
```

around the loop, but the background image isn't behind the results.

**The html result of my code:**

```
<div class="achiev-title">   Tolles Trio</div>
<div class="description">      Erreicht mit drei verschiedenen Klassen die Höchststufe.</div>

<div class="bg-image"></div></li><li>
Druide </li><li>
Mönch </li><li class="liste" data-tag="Erreicht" mit="" fünf="" verschiedenen="" klassen="" die="" höchststufe.="">
```

As you can see the `<div class="bg-image"></div>` isn't around the `foreach` output. How can I fix this?

Comment: Your html is obviously invalid and browser rebuilds it. Format html properly and see whats wrong. For example - do you really need two `</ul>`?

Comment: Where are the quotes after the assignment operator for data-tag?  It looks as though the apostrophes are there to print lengthy, interrupted string literals.  I think this may have messed up the servlet programming by not providing quotes around that data-tag attribute.

Comment: Please, access your page, copy the received result (as text, right click page, then select view page source code), and post it whole on your question as well. The excessive blank spaces are increasing the size, for no good reason as well.

Comment: also looks like you have a loose concatenate operator near the end by höchststufe.="">

Comment: Do you have a css file with the styles for that class bg-image? That is all that is where that would come from.

Comment: Please format better your code to make it easier for the others (and for you) to read!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the line near data-tag to read:

```
 data-tag="', $item['description'], '">
```

and go clean up that

```
hochststufe.=""
```

to be

```
hochststufe="">
```

Also, it may be easier for you to write your PHP servlet in a manner more like this:

```
<?php

// Current manner     
$someVal = "something";
echo ' some html ' , $someVal , ' 
    some more html '; 


// Another way to write the values, without relying on 
// similar puncutation marks and arbitrary spacing.

$someArray = array("blip", "blap");
$index = 0;

$htmlOutput = "";
$htmlOutput .= "\n\t\t<some html commands with attribute=\" ";
$htmlOutput .= $someArray[$index++];
$htmlOutput .= " \" another attribute=\"blah\" ></some> ";

$htmlOutput .= "\n\t\t<some html commands with attribute=\" ";
$htmlOutput .= $someArray[$index];
$htmlOutput .= " \" another attribute=\"blah\" ></some> ";

echo $htmlOutput;

?>
```

Which makes for a difference in the source output like:

```
<body>
 some html something some more html 
        <some html commands with attribute=" blip " another attribute="blah" ></some> 
        <some html commands with attribute=" blap " another attribute="blah" ></some>  
</body>
```